# It's possible to disable empty Paragraphs <p>

Tags: jquery, editor, paragraphs

if i get from my cms editor`<p></p>` it's possible to delete empty paragraphs? I have found the way how it is possible to delete at wordpress, but i use now joomla, may be possible to disable empty paragrahps wit jquery?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17248/how-to-disable-empty-p-tags-in-comment-text

Comment: Well, what is the relation between the linked jsfiddle and your question??? So why posting it?

Comment: sorry, relation is there, i have tried here to solve this... but that's not important...

Comment: So, the only thing you've tried is copy pasting two different stackoverflow solutions, one of which is completely unrelated, and the other clearly states that it **doesn't** solve the problem? Yes, you can use jQuery to do this, but it's probably the wrong tool for the job. I would look into modifying the `wpautop` filter mentioned in the linked SO question, or maybe even adding my own custom filter to apply, removing the unwanted `<p></p>` before it even gets outputted to the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("p:empty").remove();
```

is all you have to do

Answer (score 1):

This will find all `p` tags that have no text within the tag:

```
$('p').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() == "") {
         $(this).remove();
     }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6mtRK/)

Comment: I hava tried this and other solutions, i get from editor alsway <p> </p> - and between open-and close tag i have a space " ", i have tried to edit your request so: if ($(this).text() == " ") {, but that not work, issues wit trim have also not effect, i have also seen for js errors, but there are now js errors

Answer (score 1):

Looks like work, even i'd suggest to use .filter():

```
$('p:empty').remove();
```

Using filter():

```
$('p').filter(function() { return $.trim($(this).text()) === 0}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery:

```
$("p").each(function () {  
    if ($(this).html().trim().length === 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```